# SQL - Best practice way of cycling through rows by Date

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, date

Im working on a JAVA form and SQLite Database driven app that takes in some information for each day and sometimes multiple times in a day.

The input form and Database would look like this

[image: Input Form]

[image: Database Layout]

What i would like to do is have the ability to press "Next record" or "Previous Record" and it will go to the next record by Date but the record could have the same day set.

If i go by ID theres no way of it not messing up when i delete rows.
If someone comes in and edits an old record date it will also mess up the cycle if i go by ID.

How to developers generally cycle through records like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a Date/ID index (assmuing there are no other criteria), and then use these columns as part of your `ORDER BY`. This will ensure all records on the same day, maintain a consistent order.

You can also use relative filters to the current record this way i.e.

```
WHERE (new.date = old.date AND new.ID > old.ID)
OR new.date > old.date
```

combine this with your ordering, and you'll have the 'next record' as your first result each time.

previous is similar - just reverse the criteria.

The resulting query should look something like:

```
SELECT   TOP 1 *
FROM     Table t
WHERE    (t.Date = old.Date AND t.ID > old.ID)
OR       t.Date > old.Date
ORDER BY Date, ID
```

The old.Date and old.ID are parameters passed in (am guessing SQLite uses a similar TOP to MSSQL, as opposed to Rownum or limits).

Comment: Im new enough to SQL myself. If i make the Date an Index could there be multiple entries with the same Date? change it to DateTime maybe?

Comment: sorry, I meant a composite index using date and ID. :) - also there is no need for an index to be unique anyway. ;) (not greatly familiar with SQLite, so there may be restrictions I don't know about)

Comment: I wouldn't make ID and date the same index, otherwise you can not filter on the date without filtering on the ID, too. Make ID the primary key and put an non-unique index on the date.

Comment: By the way: This will randomly pick an entry, not the next one.

Comment: I don't follow, would you mind expanding why so I can understand? - I can ask it as a seperate question if you want to hunt rep ;)

Comment: If you just write `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE new.date > old.date` this gets a record *set*, not a single record. Even if you limit to only one result, this could be *any* random entry with later date, as you do not have an `ORDER` clause.

Comment: ah sorry, I mentioned earlier on in the answer that the ORDER BY was the most important part - I'll edit and include the full query I meant. :)

Comment: Mine is designed such that, those would be considered previous records, I will look at yours, and see what I deduce from that.

Comment: I deleted my solution as after all "special case"-considering became equal to yours :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60676/discussion-between-guy-flavell-and-thorsten-dittmar).